# Find distribution parameters of censored variable in R

Tags: r, statistics, truncation

I have a dataset consisting of a single variable which happens to be left censored (censoring point is 0). I believe that the latent variable (i.e. the variable before censoring takes place) more or less follows a normal distribution. How can I - using R - find the parameters of this distribution?

Given the wealth of R-packages I'm surprised I have not been able to find any that easily solves the problem at hand. Judging by the name the **fitdistcens**-function from the fitdistrplus-package might be useful in this context. But if I read the documentation correctly - which I doubt - the function requires two columns, one of which should contain the uncensored data:

> ***censdata** A dataframe of two columns respectively named left and right, describing each observed value as an interval. The left column contains either NA for left censored observations, the left bound of the interval for interval censored observations, or the observed value for non-censored observations. The right column contains either NA for right censored observations, the right bound of the interval for interval censored observations, or the observed value for non-censored observations.*

Does this mean that the function can't be used for my purpose? If so what are the alternatives?

Help (possibly involving an example) is much appreciated.

Comment: please add an example dataset, the code you tried and the expected output

Comment: My data consists of a single vector with 200 observation, of which only 40 entries non-zero values.

Comment: Eg `y<-c(0,0,0,1.43,0,2.27,0,0,0,0,.84,0)`

Comment: Dunno how to use `censdata`, but if I remember correctly, the likelihood function for censored data is not too complicated. Each censored datum (assuming independence) contributes a factor `integral(p(x), x, -infinity, a)` where `a` is the cut-off point (0 as you described it) and `p(x)` is the density function. So that will be a term which you can express in terms of `erf` and, I guess, you can at least minimize the log-likelihood numerically even if you can't find an exact solution. I haven't worked out the details but I hope this is enough to get going.

Comment: @RobertDodier I'm just surprised no one has implemented the MLE procedure already. This really isn't that exotic. But you are absolutely right; if no one comes up with an easier solution that is the way to go.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, I would suppose someone has done it somehow already. If it still matters, maybe you can contact the author(s) of the fitdistrplus package and ask them about it. But it looks like you have a solution already, that's terrific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same thing and I believe you just have to specify the minimum value on the right side and NA on the left side when an observation has been censored.

For example, here's a simulation showing that much:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

# These are the actual parameters of the right-censored, normal distribution to be fit
mu <- 10; sd <- 10; 

# Number of samples to use
n <- 100000; 

# Minimum value to censor at
x.min <- 0

# Create the sample to fit
x <- rnorm(n, mu, sd)


d <- data.frame(
  left= ifelse(x <= x.min, NA, x),   # Assign left side as NA when censored
  right=ifelse(x <= x.min, x.min, x) # Assign right side as x.min when censored
)
fitdistcens(d, 'norm')
# Fitting of the distribution ' norm ' on censored data by maximum likelihood 
# Parameters:
#      estimate
# mean 10.01450
# sd   10.00456
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up chunk of R-code that seems to do the job:

```
#Set censoring point
a<-0 

#Generate random censored data
x<-rnorm(1000,-1,2)
x[x<a]<-a
length(which(x>a))

#Log-likelihood function
ll<-function(u=0,s=1){
-sum(pnorm(a,mean=u,sd=s,log=TRUE)*(x==a)+dnorm(x,mean=u,sd=s,log=TRUE)*(x>a))
}

#Run MLE - change initiation values (u and s)
require("stats4")
est<-mle(ll,start=list(u=0,s=1),,method="L-BFGS-B",lower = c(-Inf, 0))

#Show fit
plot.ecdf(x)
xplot<-seq(from=a,to=max(x),length=100)
lines(xplot,pnorm(xplot,mean=est@coef[1],sd=est@coef[2]),col="green")
```